# Chrome cannot load action icon depending on policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change my extension's icon from a background page (manifest v2), using:

> chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:{'48':'images/iconready.png'}});

By default, I get a surprising:

```
Could not load action icon 'images/iconready.png'.
Context
_generated_background_page.html
Stack Trace
_generated_background_page.html:0 (anonymous function)
Nothing to see here, move along.
```

as well as:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not load action icon 'images/iconready.png'.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "my description",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "hello.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
   "web_accessible_resources":[
   "images/icon.png",
   "images/iconbusy.png",
   "images/icondisc.png",
   "images/iconready.png"
   ],
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "activeTab", "tabs",
    "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking",
    "proxy",
    "webNavigation",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
 }
```

(note that I've tried it with and without the "web_accessible_resources" part, it doesn't change a thing)

I've tried adding the following, and suddenly, it works, and I DO see the icon changing, which means that my code, path etc. is valid:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self';img-src *",
```

However, my extension does need connect permissions, thus the previous line MUST be something like this instead:

```
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self';connect-src *;img-src *",
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the connect-src permission, the icon doesn't load anymore and gives the same error again.

Note that this is chromium on linux. Could this be a nasty bug?

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, any way of going around it? I've tried everything I could and am just forgetting about the icon change for now as I'm running out of inspiration on this one.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug, so I don't know how to circumvent it. Try using a simpler `path: 'images/iconready.png'` instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion, but I have tried that, to no avail, which is why I tried the more explicit version, just in case.